# Can Schotkky diodes rectify signals of GHz frequency?

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

Switching speed of PN diode is limited by reverse recovery time. Can Schotkky diodes rectify signals of GHz frequency? If yes, which ones?

Comment: Are you asking in general or are you looking for a specific product?  The general question is on topic, the specific product recommendation is not.

Comment: What product data sheets and/or technical papers have you looked at?

Answer (score 2):

Ultra low capacitance diodes <1pF are capable of operating at GHz frequencies. They are low loss Schottky types. BAS69xxx from STMicro is one example.